# Do Ram specs besides DDRx matter?

Tags: memory, desktop-computer, ddr

I'm looking to install some extra DDR1 RAM into a computer, but while looking online for some, I see all these extra specs, like "Assorted Models PC3200 400 MHz DDR1 Desktop RAM". Do any of those other numbers matter? I've searched online, but I can only find info about differences between DDR1, 2, and 3.

Comment: They all matter.  For instance 400Mhz is the frequency..  Check your motherboard manual for support memory configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on who you ask, and on the speed of the system. This is a particularly old system, and many of the considerations that you'd have with a modern system do not play a part here.

I think the most important thing to start with is, your ram is *only* as fast as the slowest stick of ram you have on your system, and the speed is the fastest speed it can run at - 400mhz is the fastest DDR1 ram you can buy, so thats a good option, since DDR is backward compatible with lower frequency FSBs. `tldr` get the *fastest* ram you can, or minimally *get ram with the same frequency as your fsb*. You can convert the PC *XXXX* numbers to FSB speeds by dividing by 4 for DDR ram

With old school ddr, the MHZ rating refers to the front side bus speed the processor runs at, and I do believe that its a good idea to get ram of the same FSB speed or better - since faster ram is backwards compatible. This may be different with newer ram, but at least up to ddr2, this is true. [Crucial has an great article on ram speeds](http://www.crucial.com/support/memory_speeds.aspx) which I referenced heavily in this answer. I'd note with *modern* ram faster may not always be the [best option](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Breaking-the-Hype-of-High-Frequency-RAM-142/), but in this case, it would be I believe

I'd also note that with newer/enthusiast level ram, when you're overclocking a system, many of them also have a [cl timing/latency rating](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/article/Understanding-RAM-Timings/26/3http://) listed - this is primarily useful when overclocking and tells you how many cycles the memory will delay to get you data - in this case, the lower the better. This shouldn't be an issue here - just get the *fastest* ram you can, assuming it isn't massively overpriced, as often happens with older ram.

You might also look at whether this is ECC ram (servers use this), registered ram (likewise) - ram can also be both, or neither. You cannot mix registered and unregistered ram, and not all motherboards support registered ram. Wikipedia has a [decent writeup on registered ram here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_memory). Most desktop ram is neither ECC nor Registered. If this is a server, look up your documentation, or just get the same sort of ram you already have.

Comment: Perfect, except all RAM has a CL / #CAS / Timing, but it really is unimportant compared to most other factors. DDR and regular SDRAM were able to get #CAS 2 or lower, but with newer RAM the increased throughput is more important than the timings alone.

Comment: Well, the importance of CL/CAS# is debatable on modern systems as well. On something as old as this, its a non issue. And yes, while all ram has it, unless you're overclocking, you wouldn't look at it at all

Comment: Thanks! Lots of helpful info here that should help me make my decision. I'll wait until I get the computer on tuesday to buy the RAM.